# good at, adept at, and excel at

Tags: word-difference

- What are the difference between **good at**, **adept at**, and **excel at**?
- What are the occasions where one is more **fitting** than the other?

While I was writing this question, I stumped over another conundrum: should've I used *fitting* or *befitting*? & How can they function differently?

I searched for the cut-and-dried answer in several sites, but no such luck.

Comment: The "fitting/befitting" question should probably be a separate post.

Comment: And the answer by @Sedgehead here might help you with the first question: http://lang-8.com/703684/journals/250229974916025919460622097193261571684.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@TeacherKSHuang** here is:

- **Good at** - average, not great but not bad.
- **Excel at/in** - very good at.
- **Adept at** - usually involves a physical rather than a mental skill such as throwing a ball, hammering nails, or driving a car. Applies to "fine motor control" such as sewing rather than "gross motor control" such as running.

---

- **Excel at** - more with sports and gross motor control, such as basketball or hockey.
- **Excel in** - more with mental things, like playing chess.

---

**Excel at** and **Excel in** are fairly interchangeable.

You could use **"Adept in"** before, however, it's archaic usage and **"adept"** can also be a noun as in:

- **"He is an adept in football."**

I would add to **@Sedgehead**'s answer that:

- **"Adept at"** - mostly means very skilled or proficient at something.

---

### Summary:

You can be **[good at/in](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49823/difference-between-good-at-and-good-in)** *{doing}* something *(but not proficient)*, you can be [**excel at** or **excel in**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144150/excel-at-something-vs-excel-in-something) *(Excellent)* *{doing}* something, you can be **[adept at/in](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341631/when-do-we-use-adept-in-and-adept-at)**, **[proficient at/in/with](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54417/proficient-in-at-with-what-is-the-correct-usage)**, [skilled at/in/with](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/69824-quot-skilled-in-quot-vs-quot-skilled-at-quot), [expert at/on/in](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111469/is-it-expert-in-or-expert-on) or [skillful at/in/with](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105247/what-is-the-difference-between-skilled-and-skillful).

Here are examples of using these adjectives with prepositions [adept](https://lingohelp.me/q/?t=ji&w=adept), [skilled](https://lingohelp.me/q/?t=ji&w=skilled), [proficient](https://lingohelp.me/q/?t=ji&w=proficient), [skillful](https://lingohelp.me/q/?t=ji&w=skillful), [excellent](https://lingohelp.me/q/?t=ji&w=excellent) and [good](https://lingohelp.me/q/?t=ji&w=good).

Comment: Note that none of these have any real *objective* meaning.  Someone can say they are "adept" at something which someone else thinks they are merely "adequate" at.  Instead the words should be ranked *relative to each other* in terms of better/worse ability.  For example, "adept" is better than "good", and "excel at" is (somewhat) better than "adept".